# Alien franchise and the Aliens Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

It look like the [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag was intended to be used for aliens in general. From the tag's wiki :

> An alien refers to a species that is not human. Typically, Aliens come from a place other than the planet Earth, though occasionally they are from different dimensions. Aliens are a common reoccurring theme in most Sci-Fi works.

But there's also the [Alien franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28franchise%29), and question on this topic are currently tagged using the general [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag :

- [Why doesn't the alien kill Ripley in the shuttle craft?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/why-doesnt-the-alien-kill-ripley-in-the-shuttle-craft)
- [Is there FTL travel in the Aliens franchise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/ftl-in-the-aliens-franchise)
- <strike>[What are the other alien skulls in the Predator trophy case?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6880/what-are-the-other-alien-skulls-in-the-predator-trophy-case)</strike>
- [What happened to the cat Jones from Alien and Aliens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6816/what-happened-to-the-cat-jones-from-alien-and-aliens)
- [In the Aliens movie, what do the Xenomorphs eat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/in-the-aliens-movie-what-do-the-aliens-eat)
- [Who sent the distress signal in Alien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/401/who-sent-the-distress-signal-in-alien)

A new tag should be used to distinguish the 2 current use of the tag. We could create an <strike>"aliens-franchise"</strike> "alien-franchise" tag and move the above questions to it, but I fear it will lead to confusion.

Does someone have a better idea?

Comment: The actual movie Alien should probably be tagged alien-1979, and Aliens should be aliens-1986. The series is *not* called Aliens. as NorbyTheGeek points out alien-franchise would probably be best. The "Alien" aliens have always been called "alien xenomorphs" to avoid such ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps "alien-franchise" would be a better tag name (without the "s"), since most of the movies don't have the "s" in their titles.  Or "alien-series"?

Would this also include the *Alien Vs. Predator* films then?